# about "static function" in c++,what is corresponding feature in Java

Tags: java, c++

about "static function" in c++,what is corresponding  feature in Java

Thank you

Comment: Which kind of static function? C++ has two: those at file scope, and those at class scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a class method as `static`

```
public static int test(int i) {
...
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't have "functions".

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: "If it looks like a function, works like a function and functions like a function, it probably is a function.", "What's in a name? That which we call a function by any other name would function as well." ;)

Comment: An interesting discussion on this can be found here: [Method-Vs-Function](http://www.coderanch.com/t/410616/java/java/Method-Vs-Function)

Comment: @dalle A function is guaranteed to have the same output for a given input. By virtue all methods being in a class, and having access to all members of that class, you cannot have functions, because you don't know what private variables they have, nor how they might influence the output of the method. `java.lang.Math` attempts to emulate function behavior, but without looking at the source you can't guarantee that it doesn't reference internal variables.

Comment: Now, you can make a method that makes no reference to the state of the class in which it resides, and document that fact, and you could get away with calling it a function, but because that guarantee isn't there, it wouldn't be fully correct to do so.

Comment: @glowcoder: I was only feeling a bit poetic. But anyway, what you describe is the mathematical definition of a function, not the computer science definition of a function, and this being StackOverflow and not MathOverflow, I'd assume that the computer science definition would be more accurate here.

Comment: @dalle Well of all the people to paraphrase, Shakespeare is at the top of my list too, so kudos for that. But if you'll notice, many of the great original computer scientists have their degrees in math. All but four Turing award winners prior to 1984 had degrees in Mathematics, taught/chaired Mathematics, or were professional mathematicians (one was a Mech. Eng, another was a physicist. Only two (CAR Hoare and Ken Thompson) were pure computer scientists.) So to say that the CS definition and mathematical definition of function are different is misleading and incorrect.

Comment: @glowcoder: I am going to have to ahead and disagree. A method certainly is a function.  It is simply a function with an implicit argument: the object to which it belongs.  The members of that object are simply a part of the function's input.  Also, the fact that many prominent computer scientists have degrees in math does not imply that the term "function" must mean the same thing in both math and CS.  Even though it actually does mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You have static functions in Java too.

```
class MyClass{
    public static int MyFunc() {
           ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The feature in Java corresponding to a C++ static member function is a static method.

Java has no feature directly corresponding to a C++ static free function, since it has no free functions at all and (if I remember rightly) no way of restricting access to a source file.

You can get in the same ballpark with either a private static method (which has "too small" accessibility - just the class), or a package-protected static method ("too big" - the whole package). But the way static non-member functions are used in C++ has a lot to do with the C++ build model, it's a way of defining functions in header files. The same concern doesn't apply to Java.

Answer (score 0):

java has a static keyword for methods.  If you want to make a method that cannot be overridden use the keyword "final"